# Missing /usr/include/rpc/des_crypt.h on Rasbian buster lite

Tags: raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite

When compiling some code that I used previously on RPi 3B, I received the message

```
fatal error: rpc/des_crypt.h: No such file or directory
```

Found out that this file does exist on RPi3b but not on RPi 4, folder `/usr/include/rpc`.

I have run `apt update` and `apt full-upgrade`. My system now is

```
Linux rasbap4 4.19.75-v7l+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:51:41 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

My RPi 3B is

```
Linux tussilago 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have tried to find a suitable package with the file. Using `apt-file` on my ubuntu machine I found that `libc6-dev` should have `des_crypt.h`

```
apt-file -x search '/des_crypt.h$'
```

I tried to install it on the raspberry, but it says it already has the newest version

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.28-10+rpi1).
libc6-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

On my RPi3b, the version is older and not rpi1 (what does that mean?):

```
$ apt-cache policy libc6-dev
libc6-dev:
Installed: 2.24-11+deb9u4
Candidate: 2.24-11+deb9u4
Version table:
*** 2.24-11+deb9u4 500
500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf 
Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Any suggestions? What do I need to install in order to get des_crypt.h?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a package and the des_crypt.h header file has moved. https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&suite=buster&section=all&searchon=contents&keywords=des_crypt.h

Comment: I also posted this question on the raspberry forum, https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=262475. From the first answer, it seems that some modules have been removed from rpc due to security reasons. Will have to dig into it for more details.